# how to call method on petite-vue/VueJS component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, petite-vue

I have a very small vue-petite component, with following template.

When button is clicked outside, I want to call method clear() on component letting it clear itself.

```html
    <template id="input-template">
        <input type="text" v-model="keyword">
    </template>

    <div v-scope>
     <div v-scope="model"></div>
     <button @click="model.clear()">
    </div>
```

```js
    createApp({model:
    {
      $template: '#input-template',
      keyword: '',
      clear() {
        this.keyword = '';
      }
    }}).mount();
```

Comment: This would normally be accomplished with template refs, but `petite-vue` doesn't seem to support template refs on components.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can use methods as in Vue JS but we can something like this

```
<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from "https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module";

  createApp({
    tigers:0,
    moose:0,
    kangaroos:0,
    addAnimal(e,number){
      if(e.target.parentElement.id==="tigers") {
          this.tigers+=number
        }
        else if(e.target.parentElement.id==="moose") {
          this.moose+=number
        }
        else {
          this.kangaroos+=number
        }
    }
  }).mount()
</script>

<div id="app" v-scope>
  <div id="tigers">
    <img src="img_tiger.jpg" />
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,1)">+1</button>
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,5)">+5</button>
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,-1)">-1</button>
  </div>
  <div id="moose">
    <img src="img_moose.jpg" />
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,1)">+1</button>
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,5)">+5</button>
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,-1)">-1</button>
  </div>
  <div id="kangaroos">
    <img src="img_kangaroo.jpg" />
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,1)">+1</button>
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,5)">+5</button>
    <button v-on:click="addAnimal($event,-1)">-1</button>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Tigers: {{ tigers }}</li>
    <li>Moose: {{ moose }}</li>
    <li>Kangaroos: {{ kangaroos }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```